# Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'

Tags: jquery, ajax

Following is an excerpt from my view

```
<ul id="ScreenNav">
    <li id="1" class="Active"> One </li>
    <li id="2"> Two </li>
    <li id="3"> Three </li> 
</ul>
```

I have some scripts which perform an ajax call based on the list element selected.

```
$('#ScreenNav').on('click', 'li', function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var index = $(this).attr('id');

    //ajax call to a controller action
});
```

Somehow the ajax call to the controller action is happening while the statements prior to that don't have any effect. While debugging I found the statement `$('this').attr('id')` to be throwing an error saying 'Object doesn't support property or method 'attr''.

I tried fiddling but face the same issue. http://jsfiddle.net/29KR9/1/. Is `$('this')` not being identified correctly? In that case how is the ajax call proceeding as expected? What is wrong with the code?

EDIT:
My apologies! The fiddle is working as expected. As @Anton has pointed out, I didn't include jQuery. However I still don't get why my the adding and removing of class doesn't work. The difference between the fiddle and my code is that in my code the scripts are bound to the list elements which are dynamic html.

Comment: You need to include jQuery to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/29KR9/1/

Comment: it can be `var index = this.id;`

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Nk955/1/

Comment: Either use `this.id` or use `.prop`. Anything that's native to DOMNode should be accessed via `.prop` not `.attr`.

Comment: @Brad, since the `id` attributes are present in the markup itself, they're both HTML attributes and DOM properties, and using `attr()` should work perfectly in this case.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: not saying `.attr` won't work, just that since jQuery 1.6 you're safer using `.prop`. (Though I still stand by that `this.id` should be used above all other alternatives.)

Answer (score 0):

please use this code in $(document).ready(); like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ScreenNav').on('click', 'li', function () {           
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

        });
});
```

Comment: then plz add jquery file reference on your page. Download jquery file and add referende on your page like this.
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">