# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

The following code resulted in error..

This is a D3 code to create a vertical bar chart ...    The code provided below result in an error ..
It uses SVG and provides the block .. but the vertical chart is not getting plotted

```js
//  the data that powers the bar chart, a simple array of numeric values
var chartdata = [40, 60, 80, 100, 70, 120, 100, 60, 70, 150, 120, 140];

//  the size of the overall svg element
var height = 200,
    width = 720,

//  the width of each bar and the offset between each bar
    barWidth = 40,
    barOffset = 20;


d3.select('#bar-chart').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .style('background', '#dff0d8')
  .selectAll('rect').data(chartdata)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .style({'fill': '#3c763d', 'stroke': '#d6e9c6', 'stroke-width': '5'})
    .attr('width', barWidth)
    .attr('height', function (data) {
        return data;
    })
    .attr('x', function (data, i) {
        return i * (barWidth + barOffset);
    })
    .attr('y', function (data) {
        return height - data;
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Vertical bar chart
    </title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Vertical bar chart using D3</h1>
     <div id="bar-chart"></div>  
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: You have to make some research on SO. For example you can find [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529618/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529618/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-attr). Do you include jquery library?

Comment: Try `.setAttribute` instead of `.attr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the style attribute function chain call to the end, as per [d3-selection](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.4.1/README.md#style) `d3.style()` documentation

> Returns the value of the style property with the specified name for
>   the specified node. If the node has an inline style with the specified
>   name, its value is returned; otherwise, the computed property value is
>   returned. See also selection.style.

so the `.style()` doesn't return D3 object, you can't chain it because of that.

Here is the fix.

```js
//  the data that powers the bar chart, a simple array of numeric values
var chartdata = [40, 60, 80, 100, 70, 120, 100, 60, 70, 150, 120, 140];

//  the size of the overall svg element
var height = 200,
    width = 720,

//  the width of each bar and the offset between each bar
    barWidth = 40,
    barOffset = 20;


d3.select('#bar-chart').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .style('background', '#dff0d8')
  .selectAll('rect').data(chartdata)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('x', function (data, i) {
        return i * (barWidth + barOffset);
    })
    .attr('y', function (data) {
        return height - data;
    })
    .attr('width', barWidth)
    .attr('height', function (data) {
        return data;
    })
    .style({'fill': '#3c763d', 'stroke': '#d6e9c6', 'stroke-width': '5'})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Vertical bar chart
    </title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Vertical bar chart using D3</h1>
     <div id="bar-chart"></div>  
     </body>
     </html>
```